# How do you enforce required query string parameters in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Given the example on [Using [FromUri]](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; } 
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
}
```

`http://localhost/api/values/` and `http://localhost/api/values/?Latitude=47.678558&Longitude=-122.130989` will both set `Latitude` and `Longitude` to 0 with the current implementation, but I would like to distinguish the two so that I can throw a 400 error if they are not provided.

Is it possible to reject the request if `Latitude` or `Longitude` is not provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload this action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get() { 
    throw new Exception("404'd");
    ...
 }
```

Or you can make your class members nullable and do a null check:

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    public double? Latitude { get; set; } 
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}

    public ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) 
        { 
             if(location == null || location.Longitude == null || location.Latitude == null)
                throw new Exception("404'd");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Accepting this one cause it has more options.

Answer (score -1):

I did this, which ended up looking like @mambrow's second option, except the rest of the code didn't have to deal with a nullable type:

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    private double? _latitude;
    private double? _longitude;

    public double Latitude {
        get { return _latitude ?? 0; }
        set { _latitude = value; }
    }

    public double Longitude { 
        get { return _longitude ?? 0; }
        set { _longitude = value; }
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return ( _latitude != null && _longitude != null )
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location)
    {
        if ( !location.IsValid() ) { throw ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When no data was sent the complex object instance will be null and is not possible call a method in a null reference object.